# WordPress and robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

I have a WordPress blog and apparently WordPress creates a virtual robots.txt file. The strange thing is that in Webmaster Tools I ran a test crawl and it came back with no errors, the Googlebot was allowed to crawl the site. but when I do a Google search for my blog it says that there is no description available because of the robots.txt file. How can it be both?

Comment: What do you see if you view http://yoursite.com/robots.txt in a browser?

Comment: Was there something else on this domain recently?